# jquery - questions on datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

HTML:

```
Start Date: <input type="text" name="startDate" id="datepicker6" value="" />
```

Jquery:

```
$("#datepicker6").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'M yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: '2000:'+(new Date).getFullYear(),
    beforeShow: function(){ 
        $('#hideMonth').html('.ui-datepicker-calendar{display:none;}'); 
    },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) 
    {
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    }
});
```

My current output for the datepicker: 
[image]

Here is my question: 
(1)
[image]
If I click text box, select the month and year from drop down list and click done button, text box should show the value. If I click text box, I click outside the datepicker, text box should not show the value. How should I modify?

(2)
[image]
After I select the month and year from drop down list, when next time I select, how should I set the value into the drop down list?

Comment: Can you please state what your question is? Just some image is not making it clear.

Comment: Guessing what you want to do is no fun.

Answer (score 1):

Date Picker

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var year_month='';

        $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the day of the month it's a simple solution to use the css while to manage the click event on the button or outside the datepicker to handle and error and repropose the datepicker itself my proposal is:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  var datepickObj = $('.ui-datepicker');
  if (datepickObj.is(':visible')) {
    var target = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    if (datepickObj.find(target).length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#datepicker6").val('');
    if ($('.error').length == 0) {
      datepickObj.css({'top': datepickObj.position().top + 20 + 'px'});
      $("#datepicker6").after("<div class='error'>The value must be set</div>");
    }
  }
});
$(function () {
  $("#datepicker6").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'M yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: '2000:'+(new Date).getFullYear(),
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      var e = window.event || window.Event;
      var target = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
      if ($(target).is('button.ui-datepicker-close')) {
        $('.error').remove();
        var newDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
.error {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<form>
    Start Date:<br>
    <input type="text" name="startDate" id="datepicker6" value="" />
    <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the date `onClose`, set the date [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear)
Since you want to use your `Done` button, maybe something like this:

```
var monthOrYearChanged = false;

$("#datepicker6").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'M yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: '2000:'+(new Date).getFullYear(),
    beforeShow: function(){ 
        $('#hideMonth').html('.ui-datepicker-calendar{display:none;}'); 
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        monthOrYearChanged = true;
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) 
    {
        if(monthOrYearChanged){
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
            monthOrYearChanged = false;
        }
    }
});
```

As for the second question, unless I'm mistaken, that's already handled automatically by the DatePicker.